# Dynamic SSL allocation in GCP HTTP(s) Layer 7 Load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

i m exploring GCP and i love the way it lets the developer play with such costly infrastructure. till now i have learnt a lot many things. i m no more a beginner and i have this case which i m unable to find docs or example for or i might be thinking in wrong direction.

I want to build an auto-scaling hosting solution where users can :

1. Create Account
2. Create multiple websites [these websites are basically tempaltes where user can define certain fields and the website is rendered in a specific manner | users are not allowed to upload file instead just some data entries]
3. In a website user can connect domain [put 'A' record DNS entry in their domain]
4. After that an SSl is provisioned automatically by the platform and the website is up and running. [somewhat like firebase]

I could easily create such a project on one server with the following configuration[skipped simple steps like user auth etc.]:

1. I use ubunutu 16.04 as my machine type with 4GB ram and 10GB persistance disk
2. Then i install `nvm` [a package to manage node.js]
3. after that i install specific version of node.js using `nvm`
4. i have written a simple javascript package in which i use express server to respond to the client requests with some html
5. for managing ssl i use letsencrypt's `certbot` package
6. i use `pm2` to run the javascipt file as service in background

after being able to accomplish this thing i could see everything works the way i want it to.

then i started exploring GCP's load balancers there i learnt about the 4 layer and 7 layer LBs and i implemented some hello world tests [using startup scripts] in all possible configuration like

- 7 layer http
- 7 layer https
- 4 layer internal tcp
- 4 layer internal ssl

Here is the main problem i m facing :
**I can't find a way to dynamically allocate an SSL to an incoming request to the load balancer**

In my case requests might be coming from any domain so GCP load balacer must have some sort of configuration to provision SSL for specific domain [i have read that it can alloccate an SSL for upto 100 domains but how could i automate things] or could there be a way that instead of requests being proxied[LB generates a new requeest to the internal servers], requests are just being redirected so that the internal servers can handle the SSL management themseleves

I might be wrong somewhere in my understanding of the concepts. Please help me solve the problem. i want to build `firebase-hosting clone` at my own. anykind of response is welcomed

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to update your JS script to generate Google-managed certificate for each new domain via gcloud:

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create CERTIFICATE_NAME \
    --description=DESCRIPTION \
    --domains=DOMAIN_LIST \
    --global
```

and then apply it to the load balancer:

```
gcloud compute target-https-proxies update TARGET_PROXY_NAME \
    --ssl-certificates SSL_CERTIFICATE_LIST \
    --global-ssl-certificates \
    --global
```

Please be aware that it may take anywhere from 5 to 20 minutes for the Load Balancer to start using new certificates.

You can find more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs#gcloud).

Comment: I think you need to prove that you are the owner of the DNS, no? To enrol a new domain name should be so easy.

Comment: thank you for the answer  but ll it be feasable for millions of domains

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere that can be done by asking the owner of the domain to update their DNS

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere how would i do it with javascript ?? i couldn't get any npm library for this. if you know anything about it please let me know